# What is the second column of `str` report in R and what does `atomic` in this column mean?

Tags: r

Using `str(survey_OM)` on my data frame indicates that all of my numerical data is `atomic`.  If I use `class(survey_OM$perc.OM)` it returns `numeric`.

I have always thought that the second column of `str` showed the class of the data but it does not appear that simple... so my questions are:

1. What is the second column of `str` reporting?
2. What is `atomic` and how does it differ from `numeric`?
3. Why in this case would the data appear as `atomic` and not `num` or `int`?

thank you.
`dput(head(survey_OM, 20))` provides:

```
> dput(head(survey_OM, 20))
  structure(list(lake = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
  3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("E-2", 
  "E-4", "E pond", "EX 1", "GTH 110", "GTH 112", "GTH 114", "GTH 156", 
  "GTH 91", "GTH 98", "N-1", "NE-10", "NE-11", "NE-3", "NE-8", 
  "NE-9", "NE-9b", "S-10", "S-11", "S-3", "S-6", "S-7"), class = "factor"), 
  date = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
  2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("2007/06/15", 
  "2007/06/18", "2007/06/19", "2007/06/20", "2007/06/21", "2007/06/27", 
  "2007/06/29", "2007/07/07", "2007/07/19", "2007/07/20", "2008/07/26", 
  "2008/07/30", "2008/08/04", "2008/08/06"), class = "factor"), 
  depth = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
  2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("E", 
  "epi", "H", "hypo"), class = "factor"), 
  depth.m = structure(c(6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L), .Label = c("", "10.9", "12.9", "1.5", "2", 
  "2.1", "2.2", "2.3", "2.4", "2.5", "2.6", "2.7", "3", "3.1", 
  "3.5", "4", "4.2", "4.8", "4.9", "5", "5.1", "5.5", "6", 
  "6.5", "7", "7.2", "9.9", "not recorded"), class = "factor"), 
  rep = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
  2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("A", 
  "B", "C"), class = "factor"), 
  sed = c(0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L), 
  notes = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
  1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", 
  "col on SE side", "lg snail shell", "not collected", "very hard sediments"
  ), class = "factor"), 
  dry.mass = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
  perc.OM = c(47.1300248455119, 47.4260808104607, 47.7349307375515, 46.4501104675465, 44.1513415737111, 43.5608499678045, 42.9921259842519, 42.2674677347574, 39.6643311064039, 
  39.0968130690949, 46.7768514928267, 46.9211608642763, 46.7877013177158, 
  47.0709930313588, 44.3241152581706, 43.7905468025952, 41.706074101281, 
  36.5061097383474, 37.4329041152142, 37.7757939038389)), .Names = c("lake", 
  "date", "depth", "depth.m", "rep", "sed", "notes", "dry.mass", 
  "perc.OM"), comment = c("working data frame of the sediment char from the 2007 sed    survey       created:", "Wed Apr 27 14:23:33 2011"), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
```

and the complete output of `str(survey_OM)` is:

```
> str(survey_OM)
'data.frame':   780 obs. of  9 variables:
 $ lake    : Factor w/ 22 levels "E-2","E-4","E pond",..: 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 ...
  ..- attr(*, "comment")= chr "names of the lakes"
 $ date    : Factor w/ 14 levels "2007/06/15","2007/06/18",..: 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
  ..- attr(*, "comment")= chr "date that the cores were collected"
 $ depth   : Factor w/ 4 levels "E","epi","H",..: 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
  ..- attr(*, "comment")= chr "relative depth ID; epi = shallowest corable Z, hypo =   deepest Z, S, M, D = shallow, med, deep"
 $ depth.m : Factor w/ 28 levels "","10.9","12.9",..: 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 ...
  ..- attr(*, "comment")= chr "depth that core was collected in m"
 $ rep     : Factor w/ 3 levels "A","B","C": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  ..- attr(*, "comment")= chr "replicate ID for core"
 $ sed     : atomic  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ...
  ..- attr(*, "comment")= chr "depth of sample from sed/water interface in cm"
 $ notes   : Factor w/ 5 levels "","col on SE side",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  ..- attr(*, "comment")= chr "comments on sample"
 $ dry.mass: atomic  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  ..- attr(*, "comment")= chr "dry mass of the sediment at that sed Z in g/m^2"
 $ perc.OM : atomic  47.1 47.4 47.7 46.5 44.2 ...
  ..- attr(*, "comment")= chr "percent OM of the samp. based on LOI at 550d C"
 - attr(*, "comment")= chr  "working data frame of the sediment char from the 2007 sed survey created:" "Wed Apr 27 14:23:33 2011"
```

Comment: @KennyPeanuts: Regarding (2), I think 'atomic' is a general term for the following data types - character, complex, double, integer, and logical.

Comment: @KennyPeanuts: Regarding (1), if I understand your question correctly, you don't know why the 'notes' column of 'my.data' is displayed as 'Factor'.  R generally coerces data into a correspondence with the natural numbers (1, 2, 3, ...) to reduce memory use.  These numbers which correspond to the original data are called 'Factors'. For example, if I have a vector ('a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'a', 'b'), R sees no reason to store six strings, rather it creates a correspondence 'a' : 1, 'b' : 2, 'c' : 3 and stores the vector as (1,2,3,1,1,2).

Comment: @Jubbles, thanks for your input.  Thats not quite what I am confused about.  I understand `Factor` in the case of notes.  What I am unclear on is why the numeric variables (e.g., perc.OM) were designated `atomic` and not `num`.  I am still not totally clear on what `atomic` is but as you suggest it is a general data type which includes numeric.  If I use typeof(my.data$perc.OM), I get `double` (and I am not sure how that differs from class numeric).  I guess I need to better understand R data types and classes.

Comment: Can you include the whole `str()` output- you've at least cut the top off. Also, some or all of the data would be useful. If this is a data frame, `dput(head(my.data, 20))` should be enough data for us to work with. Edit you Q to include this info please.

Comment: @Gavin Simpson, sorry I took so long to reply - I have added the data that you suggest would be helpful to the question.  Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: Interestingly, `head` strips the attributes that caused the behavior you saw!  `str(head(my.data, 20))` will look as you expect!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looking at `utils:::str.default`, we see that we get the usual output of `int`, `num`, etc., if the following `if` statement is true:

```
if (     is.vector(object) 
     || (is.array(object) && is.atomic(object))
     ||  is.vector(object, mode = "language") 
     || is.vector(object, mode = "symbol")
   )
```

We get `atomic` if this statement is false (and it would otherwise have been `int`, `num`, etc).

Looking at the help page for `is.vector`, we see that it returns true only if it's a vector with no attributes other than names.  Here's a data frame where `b` has an extra attribute:

```
d <- data.frame(a=1:4, b=5:8)
attr(d$b, "tmp") <- "surprise!"
```

And calling `str` on it gives `atomic` for `b` instead of `int`.

```
> str(d)
'data.frame':   4 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ a: int  1 2 3 4
 $ b: atomic  5 6 7 8
  ..- attr(*, "tmp")= chr "surprise!"
```

I see in your edit that you have extra attributes on the elements of your data frame, and that you're getting these extra lines about your attributes as well, so it would seem that this explains it.

Comment: thank you for your input on my question.  This does help me understand what is going on under the hood a bit better... I have added the `dput` data that was requested, hopefully this will make the issue clearer.

Comment: thanks for your answer.  I removed the comments (i.e., extra attributes) and the `mode` in `str` went back to expected results.  I just started adding the comments but I guess I am going to need a to find a different way to annotate my data frames.  Thanks again

Comment: +1 For deciphering the `str` code.  I saw that same statement, but failed to make the correct interpretation, as you did.

Answer (score 2):

R divides data types into atomic and recursive. The things most people call vectors are all atomic (as mentioned by several people so far.) Lists can have arbitrary levels of complexity, i.e. lists within lists and will return FALSE from is.atomic(). Atomic vectors can have attributes without loosing their 'atomicity'.

Comment: Yes, but doesn't really answer the main thrust of the Q - why `atomic` and not the actual mode? How does one arrive at such an object?

Answer (score 1):

I believe your three questions essentially boil down to one thing.

The second column of `str()` returns the `mode` of the object, and not the class.  The instruction `?atomic` redirects to `?vector` where it states: *"The atomic modes are "logical", "integer", "numeric" (synonym "double"), "complex", "character" and "raw"."*

Thus `numeric` is one of the modes of `atomic`.

`mode` refers to the storage mode of an object.  See `?mode` for more details.

Comment: But try getting `str()` to output `atomic` instead of the specific mode of the data... I think that is the thrust of the Q, as the comments above from the OP suggest. Why does it show `atomic` and not the real mode?