# Determine Cause of `identical()` returning FALSE

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two data.frames that I *expect* to be the same, but identical() returns false.

As a background, one DF comes from the Iris data ARFF file, while the other a .rdata file, if that changes anything

All the elements in x == y are TRUE, the class is the same for both variables, the rownames are the same for both, as are the colnames.

How do I determine what triggered the FALSE output?

EDIT: output of all.equal as stated below

```
[1] "Component 1: Attributes: < Modes: list, NULL >"                                
[2] "Component 1: Attributes: < names for target but not for current >"             
[3] "Component 1: Attributes: < Length mismatch: comparison on first 0 components >"
```

EDIT: output of attributes of both

```
> attributes(dataset)
$names
[1] "Class"        "petal-length" "petal-width"  "sepal-length" "sepal-width" 
$row.names
[1]   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31  32
[33]  33  34  35  36  37  38  39  40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  49  50  51  52  53  54  55  56  57  58  59  60  61  62  63  64
[65]  65  66  67  68  69  70  71  72  73  74  75  76  77  78  79  80  81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89  90  91  92  93  94  95  96
[97]  97  98  99 100
$class
[1] "data.frame"

> attributes(dataset2)
$names
[1] "Class"        "petal-length" "petal-width"  "sepal-length" "sepal-width" 
$row.names
[1]   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31  32
[33]  33  34  35  36  37  38  39  40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  49  50  51  52  53  54  55  56  57  58  59  60  61  62  63  64
[65]  65  66  67  68  69  70  71  72  73  74  75  76  77  78  79  80  81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89  90  91  92  93  94  95  96
[97]  97  98  99 100
$class    
[1] "data.frame"
`
```

output from str(x):

```
> str(dataset)
'data.frame':   100 obs. of  5 variables:
$ Class       : atomic  1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 ...
..- attr(*, "feature.type")= chr "Numeric"
$ petal-length: atomic  6.3 4.8 7.2 5.2 6.7 4.9 5.5 5.3 6.4 6.1 ...
..- attr(*, "feature.type")= chr "Numeric"
$ petal-width : atomic  2.9 3.4 3.2 3.4 3.1 3.6 3.5 3.7 3.1 2.6 ...
..- attr(*, "feature.type")= chr "Numeric"
$ sepal-length: atomic  5.6 1.6 6 1.4 5.6 1.4 1.3 1.5 5.5 5.6 ...
..- attr(*, "feature.type")= chr "Numeric"
$ sepal-width : atomic  1.8 0.2 1.8 0.2 2.4 0.1 0.2 0.2 1.8 1.4 ...
..- attr(*, "feature.type")= chr "Numeric"
> str(dataset2)
'data.frame':   100 obs. of  5 variables:
$ Class       : num  1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 ...
$ petal-length: num  6.3 4.8 7.2 5.2 6.7 4.9 5.5 5.3 6.4 6.1 ...
$ petal-width : num  2.9 3.4 3.2 3.4 3.1 3.6 3.5 3.7 3.1 2.6 ...
$ sepal-length: num  5.6 1.6 6 1.4 5.6 1.4 1.3 1.5 5.5 5.6 ...
$ sepal-width : num  1.8 0.2 1.8 0.2 2.4 0.1 0.2 0.2 1.8 1.4 ...
>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try something like:

```
all.equal(x,y)
```

Otherwise look at `library(compare)`.

Comment: interesting, i've posted the output of your command in my edit, would you care to explain what might be causing that?

Comment: Sounds like they're identical in content but different in some attributes. Try looking at `attributes(x)` and `attributes(y)`.

Comment: I actually tried that before, and they seem to be exactly the same (posted the output above). any other clues? Thank a lot for your help so far

Comment: I've also added the origins of the datasets (ARFF vs rdata)

Comment: You might also try looking at `str(x)` and `str(y)`.

Comment: ahaa! thanks, I'll post the output above, that seems to highlight the difference. if you have some time, could you explain how the atomic + Numeric is different from num? thanks

Comment: I think i got it from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5809017/what-is-the-second-column-of-str-report-in-r-and-what-does-atomic-in-this-co

Comment: Note that the output of `all.equal(x,y)` in your case is saying that the attributes of the first component are different, not that the attributes of the data.frames themselves are different (what you show in the second edit). You would need to look at `attributes(dataset[[1]])`, `attributes(dataset2[[1]])`.

Comment: @BrianDiggs ah, thank you for that clarification, that along with str() helps visualize the difference!. Unfortunately, I found out my problem is even more pronounced - str() produces the same output for the actual two datasets i was attempting to compare, not the two i mistakenly compared. Identical still returns false. is there any deeper check I can perform?

Comment: @imsoconfused `str()` just shows a summary of the contents, and doesn't show the attributes. `all.equal()` is really the best way to go because it recursively checks all the components. There is an argument `check.attributes` that you can set to `FALSE` if you don't care about those.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know the one that's different, you can use

```
which(x != y, arr.ind=TRUE)
```

Comment: thank you, the output just says `row col`. Does that mean there are no numerical differences?

Comment: Yeah, it will list all rows and columns that are different. If there are no differences, there will be no rows and columns there.