# save() and load() changes my data in R. The data between a variable and .RData are not identical

Tags: r, save, rdata

I am using R 4.2.1 on Windows 10, and I suspect the same issue also reproduces on CentoOS Linux 7 with the same R version. The `save() load()` sequence changes my list, why I cannot save my data into .RData file and later easily check the reproducibility of my results. For some reason, an arbitrary class definition is changed during the process as demonstrated below. How could I fix the problem or bypass it, to save and load data from hard drive and keep it exactly as it was? How about the newer R versions?

```
#The data is a "List of 13" having the size of 884Kb

identical(data, data) #TRUE
all.equal(data, data) #TRUE
data2 <- data
identical(data, data2) #TRUE
all.equal(data, data2) #TRUE

#Thus, moving the data to another variable does not change anything.
#However, saving to and loading from hard drive has an effect:

save(data, file="./test.RData")
#At this step it does not matter if I remove the "data" from the memory.
load("./test.RData")

identical(data, data2) #FALSE
all.equal(data, data2) #The output is below:

#[1] "Component \"model\": Attributes: < Component \"pp\": Class definitions are not identical >"
#[2] "Component \"model\": Attributes: < Component \"resp\": Class definitions are not identical >"
```

Below is a similar discussion, but here I demonstrated how the mere `save() load()` sequence changes the data (the class definitions more accurately): [Determine Cause of `identical()` returning FALSE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20575471/determine-cause-of-identical-returning-false)

Edit, here is a fully reproducible example:

```
library(lme4)

model <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (Days | Subject), sleepstudy)
model2 <- model

identical(model, model2) #TRUE
all.equal(model, model2) #TRUE

save(model2, file="./test.RData")
load("./test.RData")

identical(model, model2) #FALSE
all.equal(model, model2) #The output is below

#[1] "Attributes: < Component “pp”: Class definitions are not identical >"  
#[2] "Attributes: < Component “resp”: Class definitions are not identical >"
```

Comment: You should share a minimal example of your data that shows the same issue.

Comment: How do you expect us to answer this without providing an example to try?

Comment: Not all information about an object can be serialized to disc. There are values like reference to memory locations or pointer to specific environment that cannot be preserved during serialization. For most simple objects this really isn't a factor, but for complicated models you are more likely to run into non-serializable parts. They may still behave the same but not be truly "identical" anymore. It's hard to say what exactly is happening here without a reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, the easiest way to bypass the problem is to use `all.equal(data, data2, check.attributes = FALSE)`. However, the R should not change anything when the data is saved into hard drive and loaded back into memory. So, this is an open issue at least with the R version I use.

Here is a link to the R documentation about the `all.equal()`:

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/all.equal

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you @MrFlick, this was very interesting information I haven't ever thought. I edited a fully reproducible example in the main question, now using R version 4.2.2 on Mac.