# OpenBLAS and cross-platform reproducibility of R: how to set default BLAS for R-CMD-check on GitHub

Tags: r, github-actions, mixed-models, blas

I am working on an R package. I want to utilize the `library(testthat)` with stored reference data to verify the technical reproducibility of the package procedures in the future. How could I set the GitHub's R-CMD-check to use the default BLAS instead of OpenBLAS?

I am quite confident that the OpenBLAS can cause cross-platform variability even within containers, at least with mixed models and bootstrapping. For example, the `rocker/r-ver:4.2.1` container utilizing the OpenBLAS cannot reproduce the exact same results on different operating systems (Windows, Mac, Linux) installed on distinct hardware. Luckily, the differences seem to be infrequent and insignificant, such as:

```
Model failed to converge with max|grad| = 0.00291699 (tol = 0.002, component 1)
```

Versus

```
Model failed to converge with max|grad| = 0.00291709 (tol = 0.002, component 1)
```

The advanced BLAS libraries such as OpenBLAS seem to be optimized according to the local hardware. This is sometimes evident if you run Rocker containers on different computers which can lead to `OpenBLAS WARNING - could not determine the L2 cache size on this system, assuming 256k`. The L2 cache is an integral part of the local CPU, and the OpenBLAS within the running container tries adapt to it. Thus, it could be said that underlying environment "leaks" into the container. Correct me if necessary.

I was able to eliminate the slight differences by building my Rocker images with the following lines in the `Containerfile` (I also defaulted the LAPACK library, just in case):

```
RUN update-alternatives --set "libblas.so.3-x86_64-linux-gnu" "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/blas/libblas.so.3"

RUN update-alternatives --set "liblapack.so.3-x86_64-linux-gnu" "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lapack/liblapack.so.3"
```

And by the way, if someone is going to execute `all.equal()` comparisons to investigate possible reproducibility issues, you might need to use the `check.attributes = FALSE`. The mere `save() load()` sequence can change the attributes in the reference `.RData`, another issue discussed already [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76305344/save-and-load-changes-my-data-in-r-the-data-between-a-variable-and-rdata-a).

Hopefully these observations are helpful for the community.