# Why is.vector on a data-frame doesn't return TRUE?

Tags: r

**tl;dr** -  What the hell is a vector in R?

**Long version:**

Lots of stuff is a vector in R.  For instance, a number is a numeric vector of length 1:

```
is.vector(1)
[1] TRUE
```

A list is also a vector.

```
is.vector(list(1))
[1] TRUE
```

OK, so a list is a vector. And a data frame is a list, apparently.

```
is.list(data.frame(x=1))
[1] TRUE
```

But, (seemingly violating the transitive property), a data frame is not a vector, even though a dataframe is a list, and a list is a vector. **EDIT: It is a vector, it just has additional attributes, which leads to this behavior.  See accepted answer below.**

```
is.vector(data.frame(x=1))
[1] FALSE
```

### How can this be?

Comment: A good starting point would be reading about these functions `?vector, ?list, ?data.frame, ?numeric, ?atomic` and `?is.vector, ?is.list, ?is.data.frame, ?is.numeric, ?is.atomic`

Comment: From `?is.vector`: "is.vector returns TRUE if x is a vector of the specified mode having _no attributes other than names_. It returns FALSE otherwise."

Comment: You should check out [Hadley's Adv R Data Structures](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Data-structures.html). It's in the first chunk on that page.

Comment: Another related question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5812604/210673

Comment: Until you've confirmed otherwise, assume that any `is.*()` function doesn't do what you expect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Illustrating what @joran pointed out, that `is.vector` returns false on a vector which has any attributes other than names (I never knew that) ...

```
# 1) Example of when a vector stops being a vector...
> dubious = 7:11
> attributes(dubious)
NULL
> is.vector(dubious)
[1] TRUE

#now assign some additional attributes        
> attributes(dubious) <- list(a = 1:5)
> attributes(dubious)
$a
[1] 1 2 3 4 5

> is.vector(dubious)
[1] FALSE


# 2) Example of how to strip a dataframe of attributes so it looks like a true vector ...

> df = data.frame()
> attributes(df)
$names
character(0)

$row.names
integer(0)

$class
[1] "data.frame"

> attributes(df)[['row.names']] <- NULL
> attributes(df)[['class']] <- NULL
> attributes(df)
$names
character(0)

> is.vector(df)
[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 7):

To answer your question another way,  [the R Internals manual](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-ints.html#SEXPTYPEs) lists R's eight built-in vector types: "logical", "numeric", "character", "list", "complex", "raw", "integer", and "expression".

To test whether the non-attribute part of an object is really one of those vector types "underneath it all", you can examine the results of `is()`, like this:

```
isVector <- function(X) "vector" %in% is(X)

df <- data.frame(a=1:4)
isVector(df)
# [1] TRUE

# Use isVector() to examine a number of other vector and non-vector objects    
la  <- structure(list(1:4), mycomment="nothing")
chr <- "word"                  ## STRSXP
lst <- list(1:4)               ## VECSXP
exp <- expression(rnorm(99))   ## EXPRSXP
rw  <- raw(44)                 ## RAWSXP
nm  <- as.name("x")            ## LANGSXP
pl  <- pairlist(b=5:8)         ## LISTSXP

sapply(list(df, la, chr, lst, exp, rw, nm, pl), isVector)
# [1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

Comment: Good knowledge.  Learned some new ones there.

Comment: Technically, `chr` is a `STRSXP` containing a single `CHARSXP`.  But I 'm not sure using `is()` for this purpose is a particularly good idea.

Comment: (More details) Using S4 to introspect base types is a bit weird. `typeof()` would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer, but here are some other interesting things that are **definitely** worth investigating. Some of this has to do with the way objects are stored in R.

One example:

If we set up a `matrix` of one element, that element being a list, we get the following. Even though it's a list, it can be stored in one element of the matrix.

```
> x <- matrix(list(1:5)) # we already know that list is also a vector
> x
#      [,1]     
# [1,] Integer,5
```

Now if we coerce `x` to a data frame, it's dimensions are still (1, 1)

```
> y <- as.data.frame(x)
> dim(y)
# [1] 1 1
```

Now, if we look at the first element of `y`, it's the data frame column,

```
> y[1]
#              V1
# 1 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
```

But if we look at the first column of, `y`, it's a list

```
> y[,1]
# [[1]]
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

which is exactly the same as the first row of `y`.

```
> y[1,]
# [[1]]
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

There are a lot of properties about R objects that are cool to investigate if you have the time.